# Django: Filtering Annotations not working

Tags: django, orm

I've been having issues [filtering annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations). The models are:

```
class VenueBookmark(models.Model):
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue)
    cost_per_guest = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

class Venue(DateAwareModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

And in my view I basically have:

```
venues = venues.annotate(min_cost=Min('venuebookmark__cost_per_guest'))
venues = venues.filter(min_cost__lte=user_input)
```

However, I still get results which are > user_input. Any insights on this?

**Edit:**

I've tried converting user_input to Decimal type, but still get the same result:

```
venues = venues.filter(min_cost__lte=Decimal(user_input))
```

This is also most of the SQL I got from the Django Debug Toolbar:

```
SELECT "venue_search_venue"."name", MIN("bookmarks_venuebookmark"."cost_per_guest") AS "min_cost" 
FROM "venue_search_venue" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "bookmarks_venuebookmark" ON ( "venue_search_venue"."id" = "bookmarks_venuebookmark"."venue_id" ) 
GROUP BY "venue_search_venue"."id", "venue_search_venue"."name" 
HAVING MIN("bookmarks_venuebookmark"."cost_per_guest") <= %s 
DESC LIMIT 9' - PARAMS = ("Decimal('100')",)
```

After querying the database directly and comparing the results, I suspect the issue is Django renders the user_input as a string instead of a number, e.g.

```
HAVING MIN("bookmarks_venuebookmark"."cost_per_guest") <= '100'
```

instead of:

```
HAVING MIN("bookmarks_venuebookmark"."cost_per_guest") <= 100
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a funny question. The answer is simple, you should change `min` by `max`:

```
venues = venues.annotate(max_cost=Max('venuebookmark__cost_per_guest'))
venues = venues.filter(max_cost__lte=max_cost)
```

Illustrating it with an **example**:

```
venues   VenueBookmark Cost
     1       5
     1       7
```

- With your actual condition, if we take 6 as `max_cost`, venues number `1` will appears in result-set because `min of VenueBookmark Cost` is 5 and `5 < 6`.
- Changing `min` by `max`, venues number `1` will not be included in results, because  `7 is not < than 6`

**Edit**

Also, include `order_by()` to clear default ordering:

```
venues = (venues
    .order_by()
    .annotate(min_cost=Min('venuebookmark__cost_per_guest'))
    )
```

Default ordering injected sort fields on `group by` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I do want to take a Min. Using your sample data, if I set the filter(min_cost__lte=4), I still get venue 1 appearing in the result set, which doesn't seem like the expected behaviour.

Comment: Just for test. Append `.order_by()` to your query chain. Like this, without parameters. Before `.annotate`. This behavior can be caused by defaut sorting.

Comment: Hi @danihp, tried and it still doesn't seem to help. Is the SQL correct?